# What is client, path and data in this code?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm learning Node.js I have created server and client **.js** files but I don't understand few things. For example, in the webserver.js file, I don't know what is the use of `pathname`. Similarly, in the `client.js` file, what are `data`and `path`?

If you think I should read about the basics of it, please provide me a useful link if you can. I tried to find but didn't work.

**webserver.js**

```
var fs=require('fs');
var url=require('url');
var http=require('http');
http.createServer(function(request, response){
    var pathname=url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    console.log("Pathname: "+pathname+"Request.url: "+request.url);
    fs.readFile(pathname.substr(1), function(err, data){
        if(err){
            console.log("Error reading.");
            response.writeHead(400, {'content-type' : 'text/html'});
        }else{
            response.writeHead(200, {'content-type' : 'text/html'});
            response.write(data.toString());
        }
        response.end();
    });
}).listen(8081);
console.log("Server is running.");
```

**client.js**

```
var http=require('http');
var options={
    host: 'localhost',
    port: '8081',
    path: '/index.html'
};
var callback=function(response){
    var body='';
    response.on('data', function(data){
        body+=data;
    });
    response.on('end', function(){
        console.log("Data received.");
    });
}
var req=http.request(options, callback);
req.end();
```

The original code souce is here: [Code](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_web_module.htm)

Comment: `please provide me a useful link if you can` - https://nodejs.org/en/docs/

Comment: I didn't see the required things there. Can you guide a bit?

Comment: [this should help](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pathname` is the path requested to the http server. The example pathname for this question is `/questions/40276802/what-is-client-path-and-data-in-this-code`. The `path` in client.js is the same deal.

You can find documentation on parsing the URL into the pathname from the Node.js docs: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_url

Node's HTTP client uses streams, which emit several events. `data` is called with a buffer, which you usually will add to an array then concat later (as the code does). `end` is called when all buffers are sent.

You can find documentation on handling events from streams from the Node.js docs: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable

Comment: When I run the `webserver.js` file in cmd, it displays: Servers is running. Pathname: /index.html Request.url: /index.html Why is that? And after that, if I browser this URL (127.0.0.1:8081), the following is...

Comment: ...printed in cmd: Pathname: /favicon.ico Request.url: /favicon.ico Error reading

Comment: Because the client's path is /index.html, that's what is passed to the server as the pathname.

Comment: Because your browser automatically requests favicon.ico, it's the icon next to the title of the webpage.

Comment: Oh and the error is because fs.readFile is always called even if the file doesn't exist, so it throws an error when your browser automatically requests it.

Comment: How did the webserver.js know /index.html is client's path? It showed same even before executing client.js

Comment: Because `request.url` contains the full URL. Then the Node.js `url` module is used to parse it (there's a link to the URL documentation in my answer) an look at the pathname property.

Answer (score 1):

pathname is the path section of the URL, that comes after the host and before the query, including the initial slash if present.

Comment: When I run the webserver.js file in cmd, it displays: Servers is running. Pathname: /index.html Request.url: /index.html Why is that? And after that, if I browser this URL (127.0.0.1:8081), the following is...

Comment: ...printed in cmd: Pathname: /favicon.ico Request.url: /favicon.ico Error reading

Comment: Use this line: if (err) throw err; instead of console.log("Error reading.");

Answer (score 0):

pathname is the requested path. You should check the documentation for the `url` package: [npm-url](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url)

In your `client.js`: `data` is the response data from the server. Again check `http` documentation: [HTTP|Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html)

For learning callbacks and all about Node.js: [nodeschool.io](https://nodeschool.io/)

Comment: Please read my comments on other 2 answers. What do you say about that?

Comment: url is a built-in module to Node.js, not an external one. As well Node.js already has documentation on that.

Comment: Yes I agree. There is also npm package which _has utilities for URL resolution and parsing meant to have feature parity with node.js core url module_

Comment: @VikasKumar Seems you've got the answer. You can also block automatic request to /favicon.ico or put a handler for it in your webserver.js file